# Displaystyle for oplus

Tags: displaystyle

I would like the following behaviour:
If I use an `\oplus` in a displayed math environment, I would like it to look like what happens with `\bigoplus`, i.e., I'd like the counters going directly below and above the `\oplus` symbol, not as a subscript and a superscript.
As I am saying, I realize I can obtain this behaviour by using `\bigoplus`, but I would like to keep the oplus symbol relatively small. .

Comment: You can use `\mathop{\oplus}`.

Comment: Great, thanks! Exactly what I need! Thank you! (Feel free to include it as an answer, so I can accept it.)

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the same as what @Bernard suggested. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, while the answer is indeed the same, I would argue that this is not a duplicate of that question, even if they ask about similar behaviour and are resolved by the same command. I don't know how I would have found that question without knowing the answer. Cheers!